# Forward connecting IP address to KVM guests

Tags: iptables, kvm-virtualization, linux-networking, bridge

I'm running kvm with iptables configured to use DNAT and masquerading. However the guest machines are logging the host bridge ip not the connecting client IP address.

Is there a way to configure iptables to do the port forwarding from the external public ip to internal vnic and keep the connecting IP address? Would this be using a pair of DNAT and SNAT?

Comment: Did you say you bridged to the host's Ethernet card?! Exactly how did you set up networking for these guests?

Comment: Its a standard libvirt config viva virsh net-create default.xml; which has virbr0 for guests and iptables is directing traffic from eth0 viva the nat table/prerouting to virbr0.